# Retreive Redshift cluster metrics from db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Are all the Redshift cluster metrics, that are provided in the AWS Management Console Redshift dashboard, also available in some Redshift database system tables/views and where?

Answer (score 0):

No.  CPU load, for example, is not (by default) available within the cluster but queries run or queue wait times are.  Any metric you can get outside of Redshift can be loaded into Redshift if you so desired.  However, I recommend you manage infrastructure at the AWS level, not the database level.  This will provide more flexibility and exploit the full power of AWS.  Though I understand this isn't the traditional way databases have been used.